# Passing variable to uib controller

Tags: angularjs

I have this function that takes a variable, and I want to use it in my controller.

My code looks like this

```
ctrl.openModal= myItem => {
    let modal = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html',
        controller: 'modalController'
    });
};
```

Problem is that I don't know how to access `myItem` in the controller

```
module.controller('modalController', function ($scope) {

    console.log(myItem);

});
```

Trying to log it says it is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `resolve`. Like :

```
resolve: {
   myItem : function() {
       return myItem;
   }
}
```

Then In controller :

```
module.controller('modalController', function ($scope, myItem) {
    console.log(myItem);
   $scope.myItem =myItem;// assign to scope variable to acces in your modal template
});
```

// Example Modal template:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="template.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">modal template</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">       
            {{ myItem }} 
        </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your data to the modal using a scope :

```
// Create the modal scope
var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
modalScope.item = {'foo': 'bar'};

var modal = $uibModal.open({
    templateUrl: '/partials/modal.html',
    controller: modalController
    scope: modalScope
});

/**
 *
 * @param $scope The modal instance scope
 * @param $uibModalInstance the modal instance (injected)
 */
function modalController($scope, $uibModalInstance) {
    console.log($scope.item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `resolve` your param. Like this:

```
ctrl.openModal= myItem => {
    let modal = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'path/to/my/template.html',
        controller: 'modalController'
        resolve: {
            myItem: () => myItem
        }
    });
};
```

Now, you can inject `myItem` inside your controller:

```
module.controller('modalController', function ($scope, myItem) {

    console.log(myItem);

});
```